# Загрузка файлов на сервер и БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт который грузит файл на сервер,и заносит путь и имя в БД.Мне надо сделать так чтобы загружать/не загружать(по выбору) еще один файл который будет под тем же id записываться что и первый файл, но он должен содержать только путь без имени.

Внимание Вопрос: как это сделать?

```
  <html>
<head>
  <title>Добавление obj файлла</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add_obj_mtl.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 


<input type="file" name="obj">


<input type="submit" name="add" value="Загрузить фигуру">


 <br>

</form>
<?php
include('set.php');



$path = 'obj/';
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['obj']['name']));
$new_name = date("d.m.Y").'-'.$_FILES['obj']['name'];
$full_path = $path.$new_name; 

if($_FILES['obj']['error'] == 0){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['obj']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){

    }
}


if(isset($_POST['add']))
{  

        $result = mysql_query('
    INSERT INTO mtl
    (`name`, `obj`)
    VALUES
    ("' . $new_name . '", "' . $full_path . '")
');

        mysql_close;
        echo "Фигура добавлена";
}

?>



</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Ох-ох, сколько уязвимостей в таком простом скрипте >_<

Comment: @andreymal я недавно все это изучаю ,как  могу)

Answer (score -1):

Html:

```
    <form action="add_obj_mtl.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <input type="file" name="obj"><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="second" value="1" /> Добавить вторую запись</label>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Загрузить фигуру">
    <br>
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
$query = '
INSERT INTO mtl
(`name`, `obj`)
VALUES
    ("' . $new_name . '", "' . $full_path . '")';
if (!empty($_POST['second'])) {
    $query .= ', ("' . $new_name . '", "' . $path . '")';
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Стоит объяснять, почему ваш код ужасного качества?

Comment: да если не сложно,я просто недавно все это изучаю)

Comment: @Michael 1. mysql_* функции давным давно не используются. 2. В SQL запрос вставляются сырые данные. В данном конкретном примере можно применить SQL injection. 3. Код отображения и обработки данных находится в одном файле. 4. Нет никакой культуры кода. Через пару сотен строк будет слишком сложно продолжать писать код. 5. Не проверяется mime type файла и даже расширение. Что мешает пользователю загрузить свой PHP код и выполнить?

Comment: я пытался задавать тип файла /obj/mtl:
но что то у меня не получалось т,е  я задавал $type
 и проверял потом чтобы совпадали с файлом

Comment: почему то не загружает данные в БД и 2 файл не выбирает

Comment: Во-первых в рамках текущего вопроса я считаю, что дал ответ. И его нужно оценить положительно или отрицательно, а так же принять, если он верный. Ваш код рассчитан на загрузку только одного файла. И это уже второй вопрос.

Comment: те мне еще один вопрос нужно создать?

Comment: вопрос бы такой Мне надо сделать так чтобы загружать/не загружать(по выбору) еще один файл который будет под тем же id записываться что и первый файл, но он должен содержать только путь без имени.